# Conditionally identical distributions

Tags: terminology, iid

*This question arose from other (now deleted) question that quoted paper saying something similar to what is described.*

Given

$$
\mu \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_0, \sigma_0^2)\\
X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)
$$

would it be valid to say that *conditionally on $\mu$ values of $X$ are identically distributed*? The logic behind it seems to be, that the distributions differ only by $\mu$'s, so after conditioning on it we "take it away" from consideration. Honestly, I do not find such argument to have much sense as this will lead to ridiculous (?) statements, e.g. that if we condition on both $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, then *any* normal distributions are identical to each other. I am looking for an answer that rigorously shows that such terminology makes, or does not make sense.

Comment: At the moment your question fails to specify multiple $X$ variables in setting up the problem, so the question of whether or not "values of $X$" are identically distributed is ill-posed.  Presumably you mean to specify that $X_1, ..., X_n \sim \text{IID } \mathcal{N} (\mu, \sigma^2)$?  If so, then that is a direct specification of conditionally identically distributed variables.

Answer (score 0):

After your editing, the property of the question was changed.

Currently, conditional on $\mu$, $X$s are identically distributed as normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Unconditional or marginal $X$s are also identically distributed as normal with mean $\mu_0$ and variance $\sigma_0^2 + \sigma^2$.

Comment: Normal distribution is just an example, it could be any distribution, with any parameter. The question is about general terminology.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are right.

In fact, you can say that $X_{ij}$ for $j=1, ..., N_i$ are identically distributed.

Comment: This answer is far from satisfactory since it does not give any arguments to back up it's premise.